# How do I use the supervised learning classification in my project?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, algorithms, supervised-learning

Just to give an idea of what I'm doing:

> I'm doing a project with financial data (tick data) and I'm trying to
>   create a way make a model learn what happens before a breakout.
>
> Usually there is a disproportionate ratio between buyers and sellers
>   and the interval between the orders usually is shorter (people are
>   buying or selling faster so they don't miss out). This happens a
>   couple of times every day in the asset that I trade in Brazil.

So my question is: How do I train "mini datasets" and then put all of them together so the model learns what a good breakout looks like. I want work initially with these two variables:

1. time interval between orders and
2. order volume

Any tips on which algorithms or subjects that I can study to do this?

Here is the dataset that I have. It also include the broker which the order came from. I have 2 years of data like that and I know when it breaks out. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please try to formulate a more concrete question. Asking for tips is discouraged in this forum. Questions that allow for a clear answer are preferred over question that may lead to open-ended discussions.